# How to send dictionary in params Python Requests Library

Tags: python, parameters, python-requests

Can someone help me please I am having a difficult time trying to figure out how to send a dictionary in the params of a Get Request using Python's Request Library. Below is what the Param looks like in inspect element. I have tried several different combinations to get this work, and i keep getting an error from the API saying {'error_details': "required selection'sellout_inclusion' is missing.",'data': None}. Any help on this woudl be much appreciated. Thanks.

**Param**
selections: {sellout_inclusion: ["Include All"]}

Answer (score -1):

#### To send a get request to the server you can define a dictionary with params:

Example:

```
import requests

PARAMS = {"selections": {'sellout_inclusion': ["Include All"]}}
res = requests.get('https://www.google.com/', params=PARAMS)
print(res.text)
```

the problem can be with the API you request data from
you can read this article maybe it will help if my example didn't

https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.04-missing-values.html

Comment: Thanks for trying. The syntax above didn't work though.

Comment: I don't know if this helps but the API is Django Rest Framework

Comment: This does not work either for me